# Dropdown goes below visible area of partial view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I use dropdownlist populated with checkboxes, as shown in the picture.

http://pokit.org/get/?7c1ecede2a99c5fc2c15f63baa153dae.jpg

Here is dropdown code, although I think it doesn't matter.

```
  <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle btn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Tipovi naknade
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form" role="menu">
                @{ int counter = 0;}
                @{ string id = "SelectedTypes_" + counter.ToString() + "_";}
                @foreach (var rightGroup in Model.RightGroupList)
                {
                    <li>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input id="@id" name="SelectedTypes[@counter]" value="@rightGroup.Id" data-value="@rightGroup.Id" type="checkbox" class="input-md minimal" checked />
                            @rightGroup.RIGHTGROUPNAME
                            @{ counter++;}
                        </label>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Dropdown is located in partialview, so it's height is limited by height of that same partialview.

Is there any way for this dropdown to be visible out of bounderies of partialview, I want it to drop down as much as it can. I know it isn't the best solution, but I'll deal with scrolling later.

Could it be done by expanding partialview over entire screen?
Thanks

**Edited**
Here is HTML code, (all controls are in the same row div)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group" id="divRightGroupList">
        <div class="dropdown" style="overflow: visible">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle btn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Tipovi naknade
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form" style="overflow: visible"  role="menu">


                    <li>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input id="SelectedTypes_0_" name="SelectedTypes[0]" value="1" data-value="1" type="checkbox" class="input-md minimal" checked />
                            LICNA INVALIDNINA (CLAN 12 ZAKONA)

                        </label>
                    </li>
</ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: We need the actual output HTML & any CSS.

Comment: "Partial view" only applies server side. Once the page has been rendered on the client, there's just HTML. Likely you mean your partial view contains a div, and it's this div that has a defined height.

Comment: That's right. I updated question, in case you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a div with a defined height *and* the CSS style, `overflow:hidden`, applied, then anything inside that div that extends past the boundaries will be cut off. The only way around this is to not use `overflow:hidden`. If you set it either to `visible` (which is the default if you just remove the overflow property completely) or `auto` (which will enable scrollbars within the div), you'll be able to see the entire dropdown menu. However, in the latter case (`overflow:auto`), you will likely have to scroll to see the cut-off portion of the dropdown menu. The only way to just have it display is to go with `visible`.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that your advice wasn't helpfull in this case. I tried to apply overflow:visible class, bit it didn't work